# pygtk window moves when resized

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, x11

Setup:

- OS: Ubuntu Precise (12.04) amd64
- Python: 2.7.3
- GTK: 2.24.0
- WindowManager: metacity and FVWM2 both exhibit the same behavior

I have a small pygtk app that contains (among other widgets) a treeview.  The window has resizable=False so as the treeview is expanded/collapsed, the window automatically resizes to fit the content.  This all works just fine.

The problem is that when the window resizes, it stays centered on where it was.  I want the top-left corner of the window to stay in the same spot when the window resizes.

I've found that calling parse_geometry() with a +x+y position will induce the desired behavior.  But that's not always an option.  In the typical case, I want the window to open where the mouse is, not in a fixed location.

I suspect I need to set gtk.gdk.HINT_USER_POS, but as best I can tell, pygtk's version of set_geometry_hints() doesn't allow me to pass GdkWindowHints like the C and Perl interfaces do.

How can I make the window's top-left corner stay still as the contents cause the window to change size?

**Update:**

Since parse_geometry() sets the bit for me, just before gtk.main(), I call

```
gobject.timeout_add(500, self.fix_window)
```

The callback is:

```
def fix_window(self):
    self.window.parse_geometry("+%d+%d" % self.window.get_position())
```

While this works, it's ugly so I'd still appreciate a better alternative.

Comment: Resizing a window normally should leave the top left corner in place. How do you resize?

Comment: @n.m. The window has resizable=False so as the treeview is expanded/collapsed, the window automatically resizes to fit the content.

Comment: I think you need to set window gravity to northwest. This is the default but maybe you have set it to center somewhere?

Comment: Nope, I've checked gravity, it's set to NW and if it re-set it to NW, it has no effect.